# Set not tracked folders and files in perforce as writable

Tags: version-control, perforce

I already have some folders that often need to be rewritten and are local in my .p4ignore however they are still always automatically marked as not writable. how can i exclude these files that are not on the server and not tracked from being made none writable. a file like this would be the unreal autosave folder for example

Answer (score 1):

These files aren't really "untracked" the way you currently have things set up.  If the files are being made readable, it means that somebody else has added them to the depot and you're syncing them down.  `.p4ignore` stops you from adding files from your workspace, but it doesn't stop anyone else from adding them to the depot and it doesn't stop you from syncing them down.

Luckily Perforce allows you to configure what files are and aren't part of your workspace.  Edit your *client view* to exclude the files; the next time you sync they'll be removed, and from that point on you'll only ever see files there if you put them there yourself; Perforce will not touch them, including making them read-only.

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r13.1/manuals/p4v/Defining_a_client_view.html
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.3/manuals/p4v/streams.views.html
[https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/o.views.html#:~:text=To%20create%20a%20client%20view,to%20evolve%20along%20different%20paths](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/o.views.html#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20client%20view,to%20evolve%20along%20different%20paths).

Once your client view is configured correctly, `.p4ignore` is no longer necessary.  If you're using streams, configuring the stream view to exclude unwanted files will automatically propagate the change to all workspaces of that stream.

Comment: They are not pulled down they dont exist on the depot, because of that, everytime i want to "check them out" to make them writable they stay unwritable with the error message saying that they dont exist on the server and cannot be checked out because of that

Comment: If they don't exist in the depot, Perforce isn't what's making them read-only.